# Qt Linguist: Only .ui-based widgets are translated, other contexts/widgets not

Tags: c++, qt, translation

I've checked many questions related to Qt Linguist, but I have not found a solution for my particular problem.

I have a (Chinese) translation file in which many fields are correctly filled in.

[image: Chinese translation]

My problem is that in my application only the translations of .ui-based contexts/widgets are working correctly. Other contexts (such as VideoWidget) are not being translated.

The translation itself seems to be present

```
QString test1 = QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Report");
QString test2 = QApplication::translate("VideoWidget", "Left");
```

test1 = "报告"

test2 = "报告"

VideoWidget is derived from QGroupBox and is, as said, not generated from a .ui file.

What do I need to do to get the translation of non-.ui-based widgets/contexts to work? As far as I know, the translators are stored globally in QApplication, so I can't imaging needing to load translators for every widget..

Comment: Could this help? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678070/how-to-get-translation-to-work-outside-the-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678070/how-to-get-translation-to-work-outside-the-class)

Comment: Tnx, the solution in this thread is also to explicitly reset the labels/texts with their translated counterparts. Guess that's the common solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly, one needs to manually/explicitly take care of the translation of non-.ui based widgets by writing your own retranslateUi()-kind of method for these widgets. These need to be triggered on a LanguageChange event.

This is also what happens in the (automatically generated) retranslateUi() function of Designer-based widgets.

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent* event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange)
        m_videoWidget->retranslateUi();
    else
        QMainWindow::changeEvent(event);
}

void VideoWidget::retranslateUI()
{
    m_button1->setText(tr("Left"));
    m_button1->setToolTip(tr("Select Left Camera."));
    m_button2->setText(tr("Posterior"));
    m_button2->setToolTip(tr("Select Posterior Camera."));
    m_button3->setText(tr("Right"));
    m_button3->setToolTip(tr("Select Right Camera."));

    m_dockButton->setText(tr("Toggle docking"));
    m_dockButton->setToolTip(tr("Dock or undock the video view."));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will helps you to set a translator:

```
QTranslator qtTranslator;
qtTranslator.load("qt_" + QLocale::system().name(),
         QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
a.installTranslator(&qtTranslator);
```

In this way it will translate default widgets and all Qt text too.