# qt translate search in all context

Tags: c++, qt

I have two context in my ts file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.0" language="zh_CN">
<context>
<name>qSlicerMainWindow</name>
<message>
    <source>&File</source>
    <translation>文件</translation>
</message>
<message>
    <source>&Edit</source>
    <translation>编辑</translation>
</message>
<message>
    <source>Feedback</source>
    <translation>反馈</translation>
</message>
<message>
    <source>Import Scene</source>
    <translation>导入场景</translation>
</message>
<message>
    <source>Add Data</source>
    <translation>添加数据</translation>
</message>
</context>
<context>
     <name>Endoscopy</name>
     <message>
     <source>Endoscopy</source>
     <translation>内窥镜</translation>
     </message>
</context>
<context>
     <name>EndoscopyWidget</name>
     <message>
     <source>Path</source>
     <translation>路径</translation>
     </message>
     <message>
     <source>Camera</source>
     <translation>相机(Camera)</translation>
     </message>
     <message>
     <source>Input Fiducials</source>
     <translation>输入参考点(Input Fiducials)</translation>
     </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

QApplication::translate() needs context as parameter and QObject::tr() searches text in global context.

I only have the source text and it can be from any one of the context.

Is there any way to search for the translation in all the context present in the ts file??

Comment: Looks you are trying to work around the system. Do you want to achieve this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678070/how-to-get-translation-to-work-outside-the-class

Comment: `&` is a meta-character in XML. If the character `&` is intended it has to be escaped with an entity: `&amp;`. Some XML readers might be tolerant concerning such issues but e.g. the XML lib (`libXml2`) we've in daily use is much more strict about this. About XML reader in Qt, I don't know but I think it's worth to fix it and see whether it helps in any way.

Comment: @RvdK Nope. The problem that you  showed is the developer wants to make Global context. But I want to translate text without mentioning the context & not making global context.

Answer (score 0):

But you can easily find the context! Recall that `QApplication` keeps a list of all top-level widgets, and you can easily enumerate the child widgets. The contexts in the xml file seem to be either object or class names, so it's really easy to use them.

Comment: In my scenario , I get only the text to translate. there might be two child widget of different parent widget with same name. So that cannot be applied. is there any i could find the context  using the translator with the source text itself??

Comment: Is there any method @Kuba